# How to mock the default constructor using PowerMock with Mockito?

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

How should I mock the default constructor using PowerMock-Mockito(No EasyMock) ?

I want to access the values of the object by doing this.

For example :

```
Class A {

public A()
{
}

}
```

Comment: Have you considered reading up on their documentation? They go through many sample use cases here: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13

Answer (score 2):

`PowerMockito.whenNew` API should be used to perform this. See this link for further information: [How to mock construction of new objects](https://github.com/jayway/powermock)

Answer (score 0):

from [docs](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#How_to_mock_construction_of_new_objects)

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(X.class)
public class XTest {
        @Test
        public void test() {
                whenNew(MyClass.class).withNoArguments().thenThrow(new IOException("error message"));

                X x = new X();
                x.y(); // y is the method doing "new MyClass()"

                ..
        }
}
```