# Mockito skip new object call

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
    public void createId() {

           Customer cust = findCustomer(this.custId);
           Address addr = findAddress(this.addr);

           UniqueIdCreator create = new UniqueIdCreator(this.custId, this.addr, this.name);
           create.populate();
           this.name.setName(create.customerName.getName());
}
```

for the above how do I skip method `create.populate();`

Here is what I did:

```
@Test
public void test {
    Customer cust = new Customer();
    cust.setId(1);
    cust.setName("test");
    Address addr = new Address();
    addr.setStreet("test-st");
    IdCreator c = Mockito.spy(new IdCreator(cust,addr,null));
    getDao.getPresist.add(cust);
    getDao.getPresist.add(addr);
    c.createId();
}
```

error: null pointer inside of method 'create.populate();'

This is for mockito only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock the default constructor using PowerMock with Mockito?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501572/how-to-mock-the-default-constructor-using-powermock-with-mockito)

Comment: Mock constructor, then mock method invocation.

Comment: I tried this but it seems it is still not skipping.
I tried mock method b then call b with do nothing. but tc.methodA still reads b

Comment: Show your attempts. Maybe we can find what is wrong with them.

Comment: not sure what kind of information you can look at. the new object is giving me problems because i wasnt able to skip it.

Comment: I don't see any new object creation in your `createId` method. Are you sure that you didn't miss `new` keyword before `UniqueIdCreator`?

Comment: I missed it. it is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a high level, you haven't written the code to be flexible enough for what you're asking for. `createId`'s implementation, for better or worse, creates a new instance of UniqueIdCreator with exactly that behavior.

Though you could go with *full dependency injection* here and pass in a `UniqueIdCreatorFactory`, it may be much simpler to just extract the creation into an overridable method:

```
public void createId() {
    Customer cust = findCustomer(this.custId);
    Address addr = findAddress(this.addr);

    UniqueIdCreator create = makeIdCreator();
    this.name.setName(create.customerName.getName());
}

protected UniqueIdCreator makeIdCreator() {
    UniqueIdCreator create = new UniqueIdCreator(
        this.custId, this.addr, this.name);
    create.populate();
    return create;
}
```

This gives you all the opportunity you need to skip the implementation, without needing PowerMock or even Mockito:

```
@Test
public void test {
    Customer cust = new Customer();
    cust.setId(1);
    cust.setName("test");
    Address addr = new Address();
    addr.setStreet("test-st");
    IdCreator c = Mockito.spy(new IdCreator(cust,addr,null) {
      @Override protected UniqueIdCreator makeIdCreator() {
        return Mockito.mock(UniqueIdCreator.class);
      }
    });
    getDao.getPresist.add(cust);
    getDao.getPresist.add(addr);
    c.createId();
}
```

But, of course, you can use your Spy too:

```
@Test
public void test {
    Customer cust = new Customer();
    cust.setId(1);
    cust.setName("test");
    Address addr = new Address();
    addr.setStreet("test-st");
    IdCreator c = Mockito.spy(new IdCreator(cust,addr,null));
    doReturn(Mockito.mock(UniqueIdCreator.class)).when(c).makeIdCreator();
    getDao.getPresist.add(cust);
    getDao.getPresist.add(addr);
    c.createId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do the following:

Add

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(IdCreator.class)
```

to your test class. Then rewrite your test

```
@Test
public void test {
    long custId = 1;

    IdCreator objectToTest = Mockito.spy(new IdCreator(cust,addr,null));

    when(objectToTest.findCustomer(custId)).thenReturn(mock(Customer.class)).
    when(objectToTest.findAddress(custId)).thenReturn(mock(Address.class)).

    UniqueIdCreator creatorMock = mock(UniqueIdCreator.class);

    PowerMockito.whenNew(UniqueIdCreator.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(creatorMock);

    Mockito.doNothing().when(creatorMock.populate());

    objectToTest.createId();
}
```

PS: This is only draft code. A didn't check it.